# Jackson JSON Streaming API: Read an entire object directly to String

Tags: java, json, string, streaming, jackson

I'm trying to stream in an array of JSON, object by object, but I need to import it as a raw JSON String.

Given an array of input like so:

```
[
 {"object":1},
 {"object":2},
 ...
 {"object":n}
]
```

I am trying to iterate through the Strings:

```
{"object":1}
{"object":2}
...
{"object":n}
```

I can navigate the structure using the streaming API to validate that I have encountered an object, and all that, but I think the way I'm getting my String back is ideal.

Currently:

```
//[...]
//we have read a START_OBJECT token
JsonNode node = parser.readValueAsTree();
String jsonString = anObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(node);
//as opposed to  String jsonString = node.toString() ;
//[...]
```

I imagine the building of the whole JsonNode structure involves a bunch of overhead, which is pointless if I'm just reserializing, so I'm looking for a better solution.  Something along the lines of this would be ideal:

```
//[...]
//we have read a START_OBJECT token
String jsonString = parser.readValueAsString()
//or parser.skipChildrenAsString()
//[...]
```

The objects are obviously not as simple as

```
{"object":1}
```

which is why I'm looking to not waste time doing pointless node building.  There may be some ideal way, involving mapping the content to objects and working with that, but I am not in a position where I am able to do that.  I need the raw JSON string, one object at a time, to work with existing code.

Any suggestions or comments are appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT :** parser.getText() returns the current token as text (e.g. START_OBJECT -> "{"), but not the rest of the object.

**Edit2 :** The motivation for using the Streaming API is to buffer objects in one by one.  The actual json files can be quite large, and each object can be discarded after use, so I simply need to iterate through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to avoid JSON tokenization (otherwise parser wouldn't know where objects start and end etc), so it will always involve some level of parsing and generation.

But you can reduce overhead slightly by reading values as `TokenBuffer` -- it is Jackson's internal type with lowest memory/performance overhead (and used internally whenever things need to be buffered):

```
TokenBuffer buf = parser.readValueAs(TokenBuffer.class);
// write straight from buffer if you have JsonGenerator
jgen.writeObject(buf);
// or, if you must, convert to byte[] or String
byte[] stuff = mapper.writeValueAsBytes();
```

We can do bit better however: if you can create `JsonGenerator` for output, just use `JsonGenerator.copyCurrentStructure(JsonParser);`:

```
jgen.copyCurrentStructure(jp); // points to END_OBJECT after copy
```

This will avoid all object allocation; and although it will need to decode JSON, encode back as JSON, it will be rather efficient.
And you can in fact use this even for transcoding -- read JSON, write XML/Smile/CSV/YAML/Avro -- between any formats Jackson supports.